# Updating application icon Badge in iPhone 3.0, when application is not running

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an application, which lists number of IM sent by any of my friend using my application. And application icon show number of unread IMs to me. If my application is running in foreground, I can update badge by calling web service every 1 minute which will return number of unread IMs. Suppose, if the person is using iPhone3.0 and application is not running, how can i update the badge? Push notification without alert, but with just number of unread IMs as badge number will work?

Please advice, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if the user enables push notifications and allowes it for your app then you can use them to just adjust the badge counter.

Comment: Yes, you should sign up for push notifications of **UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge** type and in application handle them and update application badge. Don't forget set correct type for notification payload on your server.

Comment: Wow, Great, i will check this now, and get back to you. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I tried sending push notification without alert, just sending badges . And it works only when the application is in active state, the delegate method "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is getting called only when application is active state. I wonder how can i make this work when application goes background in iOS4 and when application is not running in iOS3.0. Please advice, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At last, we found the problem, the problem is passing badge parameter as string in JSON payload, Now we are sending it as number, so even when the application is in background, badge getting set properly. 
Thank you for your all help.